# Using Query on SQL Server database to count records of some type and grouped by some foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, select

I'm developing an ASP.NET web application using Visual Studio 2010 professional and a SQL Server database. I have some records in the database for the next tables:
[image]

Is there a way to calculate for example with only one query, how many records in table sarcini has stare_task (means task_state) = closed according to each employee(angajat) foreign key in sarcini?
I think this is too ambigous  but I don't know how to explain exactly what I mean.

Comment: What version of sql server, also why can't you explain what you mean -- it is hard to answer if you can't.

Comment: Explain how to tell which ones are "share_task".  You want the ones that have this field non-null?

Comment: @TBogdan: Are you using any ORM ?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 , The main idea is that I would like to draw a pie chart that will be segmented by angajati.id_angajat(angajati=employee)  example : 3 records(3 employees) => 3 segments in the pie, but the main issue is the next one: 100% of the pie means all the sarcini records that have stare_tast ='closed', so I have to count how many of the SARCINI records for each id_angajat have stare_task = 'closed'... I hope this explains what I want to do better..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select
    id_angajat
    ,sum(case when stare_task = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) as [Closed_Records]
From sarcini
Group by id_angajat
```

Assuming MS SQL Server and that you are just using table sarcini..

**Edit:** Sql Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2c89/2

Comment: aaaaaaa, stare_task='closed' , I don't refer to them as closed records...my bad, that's only a string attribute ....

Comment: So what does stare_task display when the record is closed?